# Connecting jsf to postgres, what's wrong?

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

So here's my problem in short : I am trying to create a JSF page and a Java class to connect to a DB (postgres). The goal is to extract a result from the DB and then show it on the JSF, pretty simple right ?

My code is the following :

The JSF is :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        Hello from Facelets
        <p>${calendar.form}</p>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

As for Java :

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean(name="calendar")
@ViewScoped 
@RequestScoped

public class Calendar {
    private String form = null;

    public String getForm() {
        return form;
    }

    public void setForm(String form) {
        this.form = form;
    }

    public Calendar(){
        /* Connexion à la base de données */
        String url = "jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/postgres";
        String utilisateur = "postgres";
        String motDePasse = "123456789";
        Connection connexion = null;
        try {
            connexion = DriverManager.getConnection( url, utilisateur, motDePasse );

            /* Ici, nous placerons nos requêtes vers la BDD */
            /* ... */
            /* Création de l'objet gérant les requêtes */
            Statement statement = connexion.createStatement();
            /* Exécution d'une requête de lecture */
            ResultSet resultat = statement.executeQuery( "SELECT *  FROM detaillant WHERE date= \"2013-04-25\" ;" );
            resultat.next();
            setForm(resultat.getString( "form" )); 
                /* Traiter ici les valeurs récupérées. */
        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            /* Gérer les éventuelles erreurs ici */
        } finally {
            if ( connexion != null )
                try {
                    /* Fermeture de la connexion */
                    connexion.close();
                } catch ( SQLException ignore ) {
                    /* Si une erreur survient lors de la fermeture, il suffit de l'ignorer. */
                }
        }
      }//END of constructor

}
```

In my web.xml I have made sure to launch my app from the JSF page (which in my case was named index) as follows :

```
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

So, I thought I had it until I run the whole thing just to be bumped into one little problem : the page appears, still I don't get any value !

So, any idea about what I might change to have it working ? Thanks in advance !

Edit :

The stacktrace contained as a result the following :

```
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Impossible dinstancier la classe Calendar.
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:193)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:71)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:147)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:224)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:85)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:401)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:410)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/postgres
    at Calendar.<init>(Calendar.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:374)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:188)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/postgres
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:604)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
    at Calendar.<init>(Calendar.java:27)
    ... 48 more
```

For a beginer, this is one hot served plate haha...

Comment: How are you accessing to your page? Why don't you catch the SQLException in order to see if there's a problem in your PostgreSQL connection code? Also, a managed bean must have only one scope, yours have `@ViewScoped` and `@RequestScoped`, remove the last one.

Comment: Ok, removed the @RequestScoped, not working yet. About the SQLException : I am catching it, just not doing anything with it :p I've added a println() to see if it's invoked, it appears not so... Do you think it's a connection problem ? I thought it was jsf's problem (or me making some mistake, so to speak...).

Comment: Well, show how you access to your page a.k.a. the address you write in the browser

Comment: I have added (as you recommended) this piece of code into the catch exception brackets : System.out.println("erratum connectum !"); and It's on, erratum connectum it is ! (didn't see it at first, was blind I guess...). As for accessing the page : I just added the name of the xhtml file into the welcome-file in web.xml and it's working don't have to worry about that. So problem of the connection, wonder why...

Comment: Ok then, now you isolated the problem, if you post the stacktrace we could provide better guidance.

Comment: Ok, would love to but it's in french in my netbeans... Should I post it anyhow ? lol

Comment: erratum connectum !
avr. 29, 2013 5:17:58 PM javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot$ViewMap put
WARNING: Définition d'une valeur d'attribut non-sérialisable dans ViewMap : (clé : calendar, classe de la valeur : Calendar), I would translate that into : "defining value of a none-serializable attribute in ViewMap : (key : calendar, class of value : Calendar).

Comment: Oh no, that's a warning that appears when your `@ViewScoped` managed bean doesn't implement the `Serializable` interface. Please edit your code in order to show the stacktrace of the `SQLException e` exception. Edit your question content showing the result of this stacktrace.

Comment: Sorry sir, took me a while to find some code on how to print the stack...New to all this, sorry again !

Comment: You're not printing the stack trace of the exception at all. You're printing the current call stack. This makes no utter sense. Inside the catch block, do `e.printStackTrace();` or, better `throw new FacesException(e);`. I warmly recommend to take a JSF pause so that you can get the basic Java concepts straight first. Oracle has a decent online Java tutorial which also covers dealing with exceptions.

Comment: Edited. Ok, shall do so, thanks :)

Comment: This is the main problem: *SQLException: No suitable driver found*. Looks like you forgot to load the driver. Since you're in learning phase, you can do this using `Class.forName(<driver class name>);`. Instead, in real world apps, you will use a database connection pool that is managed by the application server (Tomcat, Jboss, etc).

Comment: Except that I downloaded a .jar for the postgres driver (which I added on the libraries file of my project , as doc pointed to me), the jar is for postgresql-9.0-802.jdbc4 while I've installed postgresql-9.0.4-1-windows. Should this be an uncompatibility problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the main problem: SQLException: No suitable driver found. Looks like you forgot to load the driver. Since you're in learning phase, you can do this using `Class.forName(<driver class name>);`. Based on PostreSQL documentation about [loading the driver](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/load.html):

```
 String url = "jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/postgres";
 String utilisateur = "postgres";
 String motDePasse = "123456789";
 Connection connexion = null;
 try {
      Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
      connexion = DriverManager.getConnection( url, utilisateur, motDePasse );
      //rest of code...
 } catch (SQLException e) {
      //this is a basic way to handle errors...
      e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 }
 //...
```

In real world apps, you will use a database connection pool that is managed by the application server (Tomcat, Jboss, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would post a feedback now that it worked, so that it might be helpfull to others in the future :

```
 Connection connexion = null;
        try {
            try {
                Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Calendar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            connexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres", "postgres", "123456789" );

            /* Ici, nous placerons nos requêtes vers la BDD */
            /* ... */
            /* Création de l'objet gérant les requêtes */
            Statement statement = connexion.createStatement();
            /* Exécution d'une requête de lecture */
            ResultSet resultat = statement.executeQuery( "SELECT *  FROM detaillant WHERE retailer_id = 101001 ;" );
            resultat.next();
            setForm(resultat.getString( "form" )); 
            resultat.close();
            statement.close();
            connexion.close();
                /* Traiter ici les valeurs récupérées. */
        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            /* Gérer les éventuelles erreurs ici */
            throw new FacesException(e) ;
        } finally {
            if ( connexion != null )
                try {
                    /* Fermeture de la connexion */
                    connexion.close();
                } catch ( SQLException ignore ) {
                    /* Si une erreur survient lors de la fermeture, il suffit de l'ignorer. */
                }
        }
```

few notes to not forget :

1- catch the exceptions and handles them via stacktrace code to isolate the problem, 
2- not make stupid mistakes as I made : for exemple in the getConnection methode the url string starts with "jdbc:postgresql" not "jdbc:postgres". It's better coding practice to copy paste from a viable source.

I think it should be it for the day, best of luck to all and have a nice learning :) !